# How to limit sublimetext 3 build time and memory for python code?

Tags: python, build-process, sublimetext3

Good day.

I'm using sublimetext 3 with its build-in python builder and the REPL console.

And of course I make a lot of errors in my code. sometimes I get stuck at an infinite loop or with extremely heavy arguments.

I've looked for a way to limit the memory size and running time for builds in sublime text 3 but I couldn't find anything useful.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify this in `.sublime-build` files - all they are doing is calling the Python interpreter installed on your system, and having it run your source code. If you feel like a build is taking too long, you can always go to the `Tools` menu and select `Cancel Build`. Otherwise, you will need to add error- and time-checking functionality in to your code to make this work. Python will fail with a [`MemoryError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError) under some circumstances (read the link for more info), so you can always watch for that in your output.